# Making variables available to all controllers in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I am using Cakephp 2.x and the CakeDC Users plugin. I am trying make variables *'editprofile' and 'profile_area_pic' available to all controllers by placing the below code in my AppController's `beforefilter()` - This code allows me to display user profile pics and works fine until you try to register a user and gives the following error:

`[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'register' at line 1.

Has anyone got a better idea of how to make these variables available? Thanks in advance.

///////////// * MAKING BELOW VARIABLES AVAILABLE///////////////////////////////////////////

```
$this->loadModel('Profile');
$profileedit = $this->Auth->User('id');
$editprofile = $this->Profile->find('first',array(
                               'conditions'=>array('Profile.user_id'=>$profileedit), 
                               'fields'=>array('id')));
$this->set(compact('editprofile'));

$this->loadModel('Profile');
$profileuse = $this->Auth->User('id');
$profile_area_pic = $this->Profile->find('first',array(
                    'conditions'=>array('Profile.user_id'=>$profileuse), 
                    'fields'=>array('photo')));
$this->set(compact('profile_area_pic'));
```

Comment: Please dont tag it with 1.3 AND 2.x - Choose only the major version that applies! Also, why loadModel() twice? Once its loaded there is no need to do that again in the same place.

Comment: Thanks mark, noted, and please ignore second loadModel()

Answer (score 1):

A better way to implement what you're trying to do is this:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  if (!in_array($this->action, array('register','any_other_action',
'here')) {
    // Do your authentication or your profile query
  }
}
```

just try to change as per your need to check in before filter it will sure help you.

Comment: using this implementation displays the profile pic but still throws the same error when registering a user, any other suggestions?

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999502/saving-data-to-user-model-from-profile-model-cakephp thanks in advance liyakat

Answer (score 1):

```
function beforeFilter(){
   $this->set('editprofile', $this->_edit_profile());
}

function _edit_profile(){
   if($this->Auth->user('id')){
      $this->loadModel('Profile');
      $editprofile = $this->Profile->find('first',array(
         'conditions'=>array('Profile.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')), 'fields'=>array('id'))
      );
      if (!$editprofile || empty($editprofile)) return false;
      return $editprofile;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: it will store the response of `$this->Profile->find('first',array(
         'conditions'=>array('Profile.user_id'=>$profileedit), 'fields'=>array('id'))
      );` if it's available

Comment: I just reread your comment and adjusted the answer to be `$this->Auth->user('id')` instead