# Saving data to User model from Profile model Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Iam trying to save value '1' to the 'profile_created' field of my user table when the currently logged in user creates/adds a profile, my current implementation doesnt change this value, any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Current profile adding code:

```
    public function add() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Profile->create();
                $this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
                // code implemented below               
                $this->loadModel('User');
                $data = array(
                    'Profile' => array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
                    'User' => array('profile_created' => '1'),
                );

                if ($this->Profile->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account profile has been created'));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account profile could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change values in $this->request->data

You're also creating $data and not using it anywhere

Try something like this (not tested of course)

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Profile->create();
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        // code implemented below               
        $this->loadModel('User');

        if ($this->Profile->save($data)) {
            //Update user here if Profile saved successfully 
            $this->Profile->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if($this->Profile->User->saveField('profile_created', '1')){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account profile has been created'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Profile was saved, but an error has occurred while updating the Users table'));
                //Email your self the user ID here or something ??
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account profile could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you need further help !

Comment: Hi Mostafa, it doesnt change the profile_created value in the corresponding user model row, maybe my field type is wrong: 'profile_created' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, any ideas?

Comment: No, the field type is correct, but i recommend changing it from int to tinyint since it's just a flag.

let's see, what's the output of this?

$this->Profile->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id'))

Also does it successfully create a profile int he profiles table ? can you show the row that it stores ? might have a hint in there !

thanks

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, all working now, I used $this->request->data instead of $data and I hadnt included $this->Profile->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('id')), instead was using $this->Profile->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');